# How to expose only one form in views?

Tags: forms

I have created a view with two exposed forms based on filter criteria and the sort criteria. I would like to display the sort criteria in the actual view and the filter criteria as a block.But when i save the view i get these two forms either as a block or as a view content.
Can any one help me to display the filter criteria as a block and the sort criteria as a actual view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you clone the view and amend it to display only the filter criteria that you require.  You can then display the cloned view in a block and the original in a page, or wherever you require it to be.